# Похожие записи по меткам в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Я вывожу похожие посты по меткам, мне нужно чтобы первыми отображались те которые больше всего связаны с этим постом, тоесть к примеру:

```
SINGLE POST (TAGS: green, yellow, black, red, purple)

RELATED POST 1 (TAGS: green, yellow, black),
RELATED POST 2 (TAGS: yellow, black),
RELATED POST 3 (TAGS: green),
```

Код:

```
//get the taxonomy terms of custom post type
$customTaxonomyTerms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'tour-tag', array('fields' => 'ids') );

//query arguments
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tours',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    // 'orderby' => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tour-tag',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $customTaxonomyTerms
        )
    ),
    'post__not_in' => array ($post->ID),
);

//the query
$relatedPosts = new WP_Query( $args );

//loop through query
if($relatedPosts->have_posts()){
    echo '<ul>';
    while($relatedPosts->have_posts()){ 
        $relatedPosts->the_post();
?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}else{
    //no posts found
}

//restore original post data
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: расхождение массивов же , а потом где больше расхождение count вывести нужные посты

Comment: SINGLE POST (TAGS: green, yellow, black, red, purple) сравни с RELATED POST 1 (TAGS: green, yellow, black),  преобразуй их в массивы и примени http://www.php.su/functions/?array-intersect   потом уже дело за малым организовать логику

Comment: @bloom так это выводит только один запись? плз можешь в моём коде прописать у меня не получается

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

...

$relatedPosts = (new WP_Query( $args ))->posts;

$realatedPosts = array_map (function ($post) {
  $post->tagsCount = count (get_the_tags ($post->ID));
  return $post;
}, $relatedPosts);

usort ($relatedPosts, function ($a, $b) {
  return $b->tagsCount - $a->tagsCount;
});

//loop through query
...
```

Comment: Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in C:\OSPanel\domains\travel\wp-content\themes\travel\single-tours.php on line 44

Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in C:\OSPanel\domains\travel\wp-content\themes\travel\single-tours.php on line 48

Comment: исправил, но вы должны понимать, что это не "продакшн рэди" решение, а просто идея.